# Creating Coldfusion mappings on localhost

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to clone my stage environment onto my local machine that runs Coldfusion 2016 using built-in web server. For invoking components on stage, we use the following line of code.

The structure of the app is as follows

```
app
   - Folder1
     -cfc
   - Folder2 
     - cfc
```

When I put the same app onto wwwroot, I get an error that the component does not exist, and it works when I use app.Folder1.cfc.test

Can I set a mapping in Coldfusion administration to avoid this? I tried using '/' as logical mapping to C:/Coldfusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/app and it works but I have multiple apps that has same problem..And I end up updating the mapping everytime I want to run a different app. Any pointers on how to approach this would be great.

Comment: "we use the following line of code." - where is the code ?

Answer (score 2):

With reference to your project's folder structure, it seems like `app` is the root directory for your application.

And `wwwroot` is the default root directory for ColdFusion server.

If you put the `app` onto `wwwroot`, and access the app using localhost:8500(built-in web server's default port), means definitely it'll give error, because, here your `app` is not root directory, but `wwwroot`.

Using built-in web server for multiple projects is not an ideal way. So instead of using, built-in web server for your project's local setup. You can do the following,

1. **Install** any one of the external web server like **Apache or IIS**.
2. **configure** the **installed web server** to ColdFusion server using ColdFusion's ***web server configuration tool***
3. Place your `App` directory anywhere in your workstation, other than `wwwroot`.
4. **Create a virtual host** for your project's `app` directory in your web server
5. **Assign a domain name** for that virtual host to access your application locally.
6. Access your application using the assigned domain name.

By this way, we can create multiple virtual hosts for multiple projects with unique domain names.

So, without any problem or dependency we can work with multiple projects with their assigned domain name independently.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. For now I went with the solution of adding mapping programmatically as described here at http://coldfusion-tip.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-mapping-to-coldfusion-admin.html.

Answer (score 1):

Can you install a local copy of IIS? If so, I'd run through IIS using the ColdFusion Configuration tool to set up the platform for you. Also editing your hosts file to route a URL is handy.

So:

1. point mydev.dev to localhost in your hosts file
2. configure IIS to handle incoming requests for mydev.dev
3. use Coldufsion's config tool to connect it to IIS so that it can serve up .cfm pages

Its a bit of setup but this is usually how I configure my CF dev machines.